# Why Doesn't my panel draw the cards?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I'm trying to make go Fish into a GUI version, however whenever I click compile, the card panel doesn't show up. It just brings about a small green and black square. It doesn't actually draw the cards. My code is as followed:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class goFishCards {

  static int die1 = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1; 
  static int die2= (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
  static JLabel welcome= new JLabel ("Welcome to Go Fish");
  static JLabel rollMessage= new JLabel ("Whoever has the highest roll goes first!");
  static JLabel computerMessage= new JLabel ("Your opponent's roll is...");
  static JLabel humanMessage= new JLabel ("Your roll is...");
  static JLabel outcome= new JLabel ("The person who goes first is "); 
  static boolean computersMove= true;
  static boolean humanMove=true;  
  static Deck myDeck = new Deck(); 
  static Hand userHand = new Hand (); 
  static Hand computerHand = new Hand (); 

  public static class drawComputerDice extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);    
      this.setBackground(new Color(255,192,203));
      drawComputerDie(g, die1, 3,3);
    }//end of paintComponent.
    void drawComputerDie(Graphics g, int val, int x, int y) {
      g.setColor(Color.white);
          g.fillRect(x, y, 35, 35);
          g.setColor(Color.black);
          g.drawRect(x, y, 34, 34);
          if (val > 1)  // upper left dot
            g.fillOval(x+3, y+3, 9, 9);
          if (val > 3)  // upper right dot
             g.fillOval(x+23, y+3, 9, 9);
          if (val == 6) // middle left dot
            g.fillOval(x+3, y+13, 9, 9);
          if (val % 2 == 1) // middle dot (for odd-numbered val's)
            g.fillOval(x+13, y+13, 9, 9);
          if (val == 6) // middle right dot
            g.fillOval(x+23, y+13, 9, 9);
          if (val > 3)  // bottom left dot
            g.fillOval(x+3, y+23, 9, 9);
          if (val > 1)  // bottom right dot
            g.fillOval(x+23, y+23, 9,9);
          repaint();
    }//end of drawDie.  
  }//end of class drawDice.   
  public static class drawHumanDice extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      this.setBackground(new Color(255,192,203));
      drawHumanDie(g, die2, 3,3);
    }//end of paintComponent.
    void drawHumanDie(Graphics g, int val, int x, int y) {
      g.setColor(Color.white);
          g.fillRect(x, y, 35, 35);
          g.setColor(Color.black);
          g.drawRect(x, y, 34, 34);
          if (val > 1)  // upper left dot
            g.fillOval(x+3, y+3, 9, 9);
          if (val > 3)  // upper right dot
            g.fillOval(x+23, y+3, 9, 9);
          if (val == 6) // middle left dot
            g.fillOval(x+3, y+13, 9, 9);
          if (val % 2 == 1) // middle dot (for odd-numbered val's)
            g.fillOval(x+13, y+13, 9, 9);
          if (val == 6) // middle right dot
            g.fillOval(x+23, y+13, 9, 9);
          if (val > 3)  // bottom left dot
            g.fillOval(x+3, y+23, 9, 9);
          if (val > 1)  // bottom right dot
            g.fillOval(x+23, y+23, 9,9);
          repaint();
    }
  }  

  public static class drawCards extends JPanel{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      this.setBackground(new Color (0,0,0));

      for (int i=0; i < userHand.getCardCount(); i++)
        drawCards(g, userHand.getCard(i), 10 + i * 90, 160);
      for (int i=0; i <computerHand.getCardCount(); i++)
        drawCards(g, computerHand.getCard(i), 10 + i* 90,30);
      repaint();
    }//end of paintComponent.

    void drawCards(Graphics g, Card card, int x, int y) {
         if (card == null) { // Draw a face-down card
           g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.fillRect(x,y,80,100);
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.drawRect(x+3,y+3,73,93);
            g.drawRect(x+4,y+4,71,91);
                repaint();
         }
         else {
           g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillRect(x,y,80,100);
            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            g.drawRect(x,y,79,99);
            g.drawRect(x+1,y+1,77,97);
            if (card.getSuit() == Card.DIAMONDS || card.getSuit() == Card.HEARTS)
              g.setColor(Color.red);

            else
              g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawString(card.getValueAsString(), x + 10, y + 30);
            g.drawString("of", x+ 10, y + 50);
            g.drawString(card.getSuitAsString(), x + 10, y + 70);
            repaint();
         }
       }  // end drawCard()
  }


  public static void main (String []args) {    
    myDeck.shuffle();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      computerHand.addCard(myDeck.dealCard());
      userHand.addCard(myDeck.dealCard());
      System.out.print(userHand.getCard(i).getSuitAsString());
    }

    drawComputerDice dice1= new drawComputerDice();
    drawHumanDice dice2= new drawHumanDice();

    drawCards cards = new drawCards();

    welcome.setFont(new Font ("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD,35));
    welcome.setForeground(new Color (147,112,219));

    rollMessage.setFont(new Font ("Myriad Web Pro", Font.BOLD,15));
    rollMessage.setForeground(new Color(0,0,0));

    ImageIcon table= new ImageIcon ("cardTable.jpg");
    JLabel cardTable= new JLabel(table);

    JPanel picture= new JPanel();
    picture.setBackground(new Color(255,192,203));
    picture.add(cardTable);    

    JPanel dicePanel= new JPanel();
    dicePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
    dicePanel.setBackground(new Color(255,192,203));
    dicePanel.add(welcome, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    dicePanel.add(rollMessage);
    dicePanel.add(computerMessage);
    dicePanel.add(dice1);
    dicePanel.add(humanMessage);
    dicePanel.add(dice2);

    JPanel cardPanel = new JPanel();
    cardPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    cardPanel.setBackground(new Color(0,120,0));
    cardPanel.add(cards);
    cardPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(460,310));

    JPanel mainPanel= new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    mainPanel.setBackground(new Color(255,192,203));
    mainPanel.add(picture);   
    mainPanel.add(dicePanel);
    mainPanel.add(cardPanel);

    JFrame window= new JFrame ("Go Fish!");
    window.setContentPane(mainPanel);
    window.setSize(500,500);
    window.setLocation(500,500);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setResizable(true);
  }
}//end of class.
```

Card:

```
/**
 * An object of type Card represents a playing card from a
 * standard Poker deck, including Jokers.  The card has a suit, which
 * can be spades, hearts, diamonds, clubs, or joker.  A space, heart,
 * diamond, or club has one of the 13 values: ace, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
 * 8, 9, 10, jack, queen, or king.  Note that "ace" is considered to be
 * the smallest value.  A joker can also have an associated value; 
 * this value can be anything and can be used to keep track of several
 * different jokers.
 */

public class Card {

   public final static int SPADES = 0;       // Codes for the 4 suits, plus Joker.
   public final static int HEARTS = 1;
   public final static int DIAMONDS = 2;
   public final static int CLUBS = 3;
   public final static int JOKER = 4;

   public final static int ACE = 1;          // Codes for the non-numeric cards.
   public final static int JACK = 11;        //   Cards 2 through 10 have their 
   public final static int QUEEN = 12;       //   numerical values for their codes.
   public final static int KING = 13;

   /**
    * This card's suit, one of the constants SPADES, HEARTS, DIAMONDS,
    * CLUBS, or JOKER.  The suit cannot be changed after the card is
    * constructed.
    */
   private final int suit; 

   /**
    * The card's value.  For a normal cards, this is one of the values
    * 1 through 13, with 1 representing ACE.  For a JOKER, the value
    * can be anything.  The value cannot be changed after the card
    * is constructed.
    */
   private final int value;

   /**
    * Creates a Joker, with 1 as the associated value.  (Note that
    * "new Card()" is equivalent to "new Card(1,Card.JOKER)".)
    */
   public Card() {
      suit = JOKER;
      value = 1;
   }

   /**
    * Creates a card with a specified suit and value.
    * @param theValue the value of the new card.  For a regular card (non-joker),
    * the value must be in the range 1 through 13, with 1 representing an Ace.
    * You can use the constants Card.ACE, Card.JACK, Card.QUEEN, and Card.KING.  
    * For a Joker, the value can be anything.
    * @param theSuit the suit of the new card.  This must be one of the values
    * Card.SPADES, Card.HEARTS, Card.DIAMONDS, Card.CLUBS, or Card.JOKER.
    * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the parameter values are not in the
    * Permissible ranges
    */
   public Card(int theValue, int theSuit) {
      if (theSuit != SPADES && theSuit != HEARTS && theSuit != DIAMONDS && 
            theSuit != CLUBS && theSuit != JOKER)
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal playing card suit");
      if (theSuit != JOKER && (theValue < 1 || theValue > 13))
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal playing card value");
      value = theValue;
      suit = theSuit;
   }

   /**
    * Returns the suit of this card.
    * @returns the suit, which is one of the constants Card.SPADES, 
    * Card.HEARTS, Card.DIAMONDS, Card.CLUBS, or Card.JOKER
    */
   public int getSuit() {
      return suit;
   }

   /**
    * Returns the value of this card.
    * @return the value, which is one the numbers 1 through 13, inclusive for
    * a regular card, and which can be any value for a Joker.
    */
   public int getValue() {
      return value;
   }

   /**
    * Returns a String representation of the card's suit.
    * @return one of the strings "Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"
    * or "Joker".
    */
   public String getSuitAsString() {
      switch ( suit ) {
      case SPADES:   return "Spades";
      case HEARTS:   return "Hearts";
      case DIAMONDS: return "Diamonds";
      case CLUBS:    return "Clubs";
      default:       return "Joker";
      }
   }

   /**
    * Returns a String representation of the card's value.
    * @return for a regular card, one of the strings "Ace", "2",
    * "3", ..., "10", "Jack", "Queen", or "King".  For a Joker, the 
    * string is always numerical.
    */
   public String getValueAsString() {
      if (suit == JOKER)
         return "" + value;
      else {
         switch ( value ) {
         case 1:   return "Ace";
         case 2:   return "2";
         case 3:   return "3";
         case 4:   return "4";
         case 5:   return "5";
         case 6:   return "6";
         case 7:   return "7";
         case 8:   return "8";
         case 9:   return "9";
         case 10:  return "10";
         case 11:  return "Jack";
         case 12:  return "Queen";
         default:  return "King";
         }
      }
   }

   /**
    * Returns a string representation of this card, including both
    * its suit and its value (except that for a Joker with value 1,
    * the return value is just "Joker").  Sample return values
    * are: "Queen of Hearts", "10 of Diamonds", "Ace of Spades",
    * "Joker", "Joker #2"
    */
   public String toString() {
      if (suit == JOKER) {
         if (value == 1)
            return "Joker";
         else
            return "Joker #" + value;
      }
      else
         return getValueAsString() + " of " + getSuitAsString();
   }


} // end class Card
```

Hand:

```
/**
 * An object of type Hand represents a hand of cards.  The
 * cards belong to the class Card.  A hand is empty when it
 * is created, and any number of cards can be added to it.
 */

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Hand {

   private ArrayList hand;   // The cards in the hand.

   /**
    * Create a hand that is initially empty.
    */
   public Hand() {
      hand = new ArrayList();
   }

   /**
    * Remove all cards from the hand, leaving it empty.
    */
   public void clear() {
      hand.clear();
   }

   /**
    * Add a card to the hand.  It is added at the end of the current hand.
    * @param c the non-null card to be added.
    * @throws NullPointerException if the parameter c is null.
    */
   public void addCard(Card c) {
      if (c == null)
         throw new NullPointerException("Can't add a null card to a hand.");
      hand.add(c);
   }

   /**
    * Remove a card from the hand, if present.
    * @param c the card to be removed.  If c is null or if the card is not in 
    * the hand, then nothing is done.
    */
   public void removeCard(Card c) {
      hand.remove(c);
   }

   /**
    * Remove the card in a specified position from the hand.
    * @param position the position of the card that is to be removed, where
    * positions are starting from zero.
    * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the position does not exist in
    * the hand, that is if the position is less than 0 or greater than
    * or equal to the number of cards in the hand.
    */
   public void removeCard(int position) {
      if (position < 0 || position >= hand.size())
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Position does not exist in hand: "
               + position);
      hand.remove(position);
   }

   /**
    * Returns the number of cards in the hand.
    */
   public int getCardCount() {
      return hand.size();
   }

   /**
    * Gets the card in a specified position in the hand.  (Note that this card
    * is not removed from the hand!)
    * @param position the position of the card that is to be returned
    * @throws IllegalArgumentException if position does not exist in the hand
    */
   public Card getCard(int position) {
      if (position < 0 || position >= hand.size())
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Position does not exist in hand: "
               + position);
       return (Card)hand.get(position);
   }

   /**
    * Sorts the cards in the hand so that cards of the same suit are
    * grouped together, and within a suit the cards are sorted by value.
    * Note that aces are considered to have the lowest value, 1.
    */
   public void sortBySuit() {
      ArrayList newHand = new ArrayList();
      while (hand.size() > 0) {
         int pos = 0;  // Position of minimal card.
         Card c = (Card)hand.get(0);  // Minimal card.
         for (int i = 1; i < hand.size(); i++) {
            Card c1 = (Card)hand.get(i);
            if ( c1.getSuit() < c.getSuit() ||
                    (c1.getSuit() == c.getSuit() && c1.getValue() < c.getValue()) ) {
                pos = i;
                c = c1;
            }
         }
         hand.remove(pos);
         newHand.add(c);
      }
      hand = newHand;
   }

   /**
    * Sorts the cards in the hand so that cards of the same value are
    * grouped together.  Cards with the same value are sorted by suit.
    * Note that aces are considered to have the lowest value, 1.
    */
   public void sortByValue() {
      ArrayList newHand = new ArrayList();
      while (hand.size() > 0) {
         int pos = 0;  // Position of minimal card.
         Card c = (Card)hand.get(0);  // Minimal card.
         for (int i = 1; i < hand.size(); i++) {
            Card c1 = (Card)hand.get(i);
            if ( c1.getValue() < c.getValue() ||
                    (c1.getValue() == c.getValue() && c1.getSuit() < c.getSuit()) ) {
                pos = i;
                c = c1;
            }
         }
         hand.remove(pos);
         newHand.add(c);
      }
      hand = newHand;
   }

   public void shuffle() {
      for ( int i = hand.size()-1; i > 0; i-- ) {
         int rand = (int)(Math.random()*(hand.size()));
         Card temp = getCard(rand);//card represented by random number;
         hand.remove(rand);//remove card represented by random number
         hand.add(temp);//add temp card to hand
      }
   }


}
```

Deck:

```
/**
 *  An object of type Deck represents a deck of playing cards.  The deck
 *  is a regular poker deck that contains 52 regular cards and that can
 *  also optionally include two Jokers.
 */
public class Deck {

   /**
    * An array of 52 or 54 cards.  A 54-card deck contains two Jokers,
    * in addition to the 52 cards of a regular poker deck.
    */
   private Card[] deck;

   /**
    * Keeps track of the number of cards that have been dealt from
    * the deck so far.
    */
   private int cardsUsed;

   /**
    * Constructs a regular 52-card poker deck.  Initially, the cards
    * are in a sorted order.  The shuffle() method can be called to
    * randomize the order.  (Note that "new Deck()" is equivalent
    * to "new Deck(false)".)
    */
   public Deck() {
      this(false);  // Just call the other constructor in this class.
   }

   /**
    * Constructs a poker deck of playing cards, The deck contains
    * the usual 52 cards and can optionally contain two Jokers
    * in addition, for a total of 54 cards.   Initially the cards
    * are in a sorted order.  The shuffle() method can be called to
    * randomize the order.
    * @param includeJokers if true, two Jokers are included in the deck; if false,
    * there are no Jokers in the deck.
    */
   public Deck(boolean includeJokers) {
      if (includeJokers)
         deck = new Card[54];
      else
         deck = new Card[52];
      int cardCt = 0; // How many cards have been created so far.
      for ( int suit = 0; suit <= 3; suit++ ) {
         for ( int value = 1; value <= 13; value++ ) {
            deck[cardCt] = new Card(value,suit);
            cardCt++;
         }
      }
      if (includeJokers) {
         deck[52] = new Card(1,Card.JOKER);
         deck[53] = new Card(2,Card.JOKER);
      }
      cardsUsed = 0;
   }

   /**
    * Put all the used cards back into the deck (if any), and
    * shuffle the deck into a random order.
    */
   public void shuffle() {
      for ( int i = deck.length-1; i > 0; i-- ) {
         int rand = (int)(Math.random()*(i+1));
         Card temp = deck[i];
         deck[i] = deck[rand];
         deck[rand] = temp;
      }
      cardsUsed = 0;
   }

   /**
    * As cards are dealt from the deck, the number of cards left
    * decreases.  This function returns the number of cards that
    * are still left in the deck.  The return value would be
    * 52 or 54 (depending on whether the deck includes Jokers)
    * when the deck is first created or after the deck has been
    * shuffled.  It decreases by 1 each time the dealCard() method
    * is called.
    */
   public int cardsLeft() {
      return deck.length - cardsUsed;
   }

   /**
    * Removes the next card from the deck and return it.  It is illegal
    * to call this method if there are no more cards in the deck.  You can
    * check the number of cards remaining by calling the cardsLeft() function.
    * @return the card which is removed from the deck.
    * @throws IllegalStateException if there are no cards left in the deck
    */
   public Card dealCard() {
      if (cardsUsed == deck.length)
         throw new IllegalStateException("No cards are left in the deck.");
      cardsUsed++;
      return deck[cardsUsed - 1];
      // Programming note:  Cards are not literally removed from the array
      // that represents the deck.  We just keep track of how many cards
      // have been used.
   }

   /**
    * Test whether the deck contains Jokers.
    * @return true, if this is a 54-card deck containing two jokers, or false if
    * this is a 52 card deck that contains no jokers.
    */
   public boolean hasJokers() {
      return (deck.length == 54);
   }

} // end class Deck
```

Comment: _Someone_ went `static` crazy...

Comment: You have sooo much code it's hard to figure out what's wrong. And I can't even test it because it won't compile.

Comment: it has to be a problem under my subroutine drawCards and the cardPanel, i'm guessing?

Comment: Could you possible post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What *is* the deal with `static`. Is it because you didn't think to instantiate the class(es) in main instead of invoking things directly?

Comment: ...and why do you have verb classes? Classes are generally nouns because they are modeling real world objects not actions.

Comment: I posted a better version. and yes I used static because of that.

Comment: Can you post your `Card` `Hand` and `Deck` class you I can at least compile this. I think I may know the problem, but can't know for sure until I check it

Comment: I uploaded the other Card, Hand and Deck classes.

Answer (score 2):

I *knew* this was the problem. I just wanted to test it first. But what's happening is that your panel doesn't have a preferred size, so nothing will appear. If you override the `getPreferredSize()` in the `drawCards`, it shows.

```
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(400, 400);
    }
```

Just add the above somewhere in your `DrawCards`. You can set the `Dimension` to whatever size you want. I just used the above to test, and it shows.

**BEFORE** `getPreferredSize()`

[image]

**AFTER** `getPreferredSize()`

[image]

---

As a side note, you should always follow Java naming convention. Class names start with capital letters.

---

Comment: Also you should learn to accept answers so people know the question has been answered. (Just looking at your previous posts where questions were answered, but you never accepted them).

Comment: Thank you so much! It appears now. You're a life saver.

Comment: Hit the check mark. Also for previous questions that were answered, check them also.